# Lambda Calculus – Defining lambda term to represent function $f(n) = true$ if $n$ even and $false$ otherwise

Tags: logic, lambda-calculus

I have a problem with Exercise 7 from [Selinger's notes on Lambda Calculus](https://www.irif.fr/~mellies/mpri/mpri-ens/biblio/Selinger-Lambda-Calculus-Notes.pdf). Here there is the exercise:

> Find a lambda term that represent the function:
>   $$f (n) := \begin{cases}
> \mathbf{T}, \text{ if } n \text{ even,}\\
> \mathbf{F}, \text{ otherwise}.\\
> \end{cases}
> $$
>   with $\mathbf{T} \equiv \lambda a b.a$ and $\mathbf{F} \equiv \lambda a b.b.$

Quite simply, I just don't see how we can obtain something like this without having a definition of division. How should the solution look like?

Any feedback would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you for your time.

Comment: Indeed, this is what I thought at the beginning, but then **we** (as human beings) have to find that $k$, it's not the *machine* that automatically finds it. Hence, to me it does not look like a correct answer. (I hope I made my point clear)

Comment: @HenningMakholm: Thanks a lot! I completely missed this point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint.** $0$ is even, and everything else has the opposite parity of its predecessor.

Comment: Does this approach entail the use of a fixed point combinator? Is there a term representing the parity function without using a fixed point combinator?

Comment: @Taroccoesbrocco: Assuming that the input is represented as a Church numeral, no fixpoint combinator is needed. The input number comes with (actually, it _is_) its own iteration engine. In general this means that _primitive recursion_ on Church numerals never needs explicit fixpoints.

Comment: Got it! The answer to the first question is "no", to the second question is "yes". Hint: think of a lambda-term representing the connective "not".

Comment: Ok, I am seriously at loss. I thought about the hint, thus it came natural to think about using the connective *not* , but I don't see how the $\lambda$-term is going to remember the number of iterations. Indeed, we start from $0$ and we move forward, but how is the number of step encoded? Also, I looked for the meaning of parity function (never encountered in my life, I am completely new to this world) and I thought this could be a way to encode the number of iterations, but I really don't see how it can be done.

Comment: @Kolmin - Hint 1: For all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $\underline{n}PQ = P^nQ$ ($\underline{n}$ is the Church numeral for $n$, while $P$ and $Q$ are terms whatsoever). 
Hint 2: An even number of "not" applied to a boolean does not change the value of the boolean, an odd number of "not" applied to a boolean change the value of the boolean.

Comment: @Taroccoesbrocco Thanks a lot! Let me digest them.

Comment: Thus, it should be: $\mathbf{P} \equiv \lambda n . n \mathbf{not} \mathbf{T}$, right? *Example:* $$\mathbf{P} c_0 = (\lambda n . n \mathbf{not} \mathbf{T}) c_0 \rightarrow_\beta c_0 \mathbf{not} \mathbf{T} \rightarrow_\beta \mathbf{not}^0 \mathbf{T} \rightarrow_\beta \mathbf{T},$$ while $$\mathbf{P} c_1 = (\lambda n . n \mathbf{not} \mathbf{T}) c_1 \rightarrow_\beta c_1 \mathbf{not} \mathbf{T} \rightarrow_\beta \mathbf{not}^1 \mathbf{T} \rightarrow_\beta \mathbf{not} \mathbf{T} \rightarrow_\beta \mathbf{F}.$$

Comment: @Kolmin: Right. The exercise may or may not want you to program "not" explicitly as part of the solution, depending on whether you have already seen it.

Comment: @HenningMakholm: Indeed, when I realised with yours and Taroccoesbrocco's hints the nature of the exercises I saw that it works irrespectively of how we define $\mathbf{not}$ (which, btw, in a previous exercise I had defined as $\mathbf{not} \equiv \lambda a.a \mathbf{F} \mathbf{T}$).