# SKI Calculus prefix notation of odd/even number

Tags: logic, lambda-calculus, combinatory-logic

I'm working on a homework with SKI calculus. I saw the hints in this very useful [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2732389/lambda-calculus-defining-lambda-term-to-represent-function-fn-true-if-n).

We basically defined SKI functions as:

```
def tt  = K;
def ff  = S K;

def inc = S (S (K S) K);
def _0  = S K;
def _1  = inc _0;
def _2  = inc _1;
def _3  = inc _2;

def not  = S (S (K (S (K S) K)) S) (K K);
(not tt) x y;  # y
(not ff) x y;  # x
```

By the hint provided by the above post, I found out that `_3 f x = f(f(f(x)))`.

If I do `_3 not ff`, I can basically get the answer I'm looking for: `(_3 is_odd) x y` and it will output `x`, therefore `is_odd = not ff`.

However, the hw requirement is to write the function as `(is_odd _3) x y` -- a prefix notation.

I tried to use the reverse order operator `def reverse = S (K (S I)) K;` where `reverse x y -> y x`, but when you apply this to three arguments: `reverse (not ff) _3 -> _3 (not ff)`, which is not the right order `(_3 not) ff`.

Am I going down the wrong path here? How to deal with the prefix notation problem in SKI calculus?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your on the right track here with the `_3 not ff` and the `reverse` operator. But you seem to be have a small amount of confusion with the bracketing. `_3 not ff` is `(_3 not) ff` instead of the of the `_3 (not ff)` you seem to be implying by setting `is_odd` to `not ff`.

Since `reverse x y` is equivalent to `y x` <sup>1</sup> we can transform `(_3 not) ff` into `reverse ff (_3 not)`. We can apply the same transformation to the subterm `_3 not` to get `reverse ff (reverse not _3)` This is almost but not quite what we what: here `_3` all the way on the right, but buried inside some parentheses. We can fix this by noticing we have a composition of the functions `reverse ff` and `reverse not` applied to `_3`. The composition of a function `f` with a function `g` can be made as `S (K f) g`. Applying this to `reverse ff (reverse not (_3))` gives `(S (K (reverse ff)) (reverse not)) _3`. Note we didn't use anything special about _3 so we could do the same transformation for any numeral.

Overall we have `is_odd` can be defined as `(S (K (reverse ff)) (reverse not))`.

---

<sup>1</sup> I'm assuming that claim from your question is true, I haven't checked myself